# Using Vorbis and NAudio to play OGG files in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio, oggvorbis

I'm trying to play OGG file stream with `NVorbis` and `NAudio`, as described in the documention, I'm trying to run this code when on a Button click, but I get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Could not initialize container!'

I'm targeting .Net Framework 4.5

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (var vorbisStream = new NAudio.Vorbis.VorbisWaveReader(@"OGG file path"))
    using (var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOutEvent())
    {
        waveOut.Init(vorbisStream);
        waveOut.Play();
     
        // wait here until playback stops or should stop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

- The first is that you cannot declare with `using` statements either the WaveOutReader or WaveOut object, since the latter is playing the sound asynchronously and it needs the WaveOutReader's Stream open
- You were targeting .Net Framework 4.5, which is not suitable to handle the current version of both `NAudio` and `NVorbis`

---

I assume you have already successfully installed the [NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio) 2.1.0 and [NAudio.Vorbis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio.Vorbis) 1.5.0 packages in a new .Net 6+ Project.
You just need to add references to `NAudio.Vorbis` and `NAudio.Wave`

Targeting .Net 6+, `nullable` enabled.

Add two Button Controls to a Form, one named `btnPlayAudio` and the other `btnStopPlayback`, initially disabled; subscribe to their Click event using the event handlers shown here.

The WaveOutReader and the WaveOut object that acts as player are declared as instance Fields, initially set to `null`.

When you press the Play Audio Button, the audio Stream and the Player are initialized, calling the `WaveOutInit()` method, which also subscribes to the WaveOut object's `PlaybackStopped` event.
When you call the WaveOut object's `Stop()` method or the OGG playback terminates, this event is raised. Here, the `Stop()` method is called in the `btnStopPlayback` click handler.

When this happens, another method, `WaveOutReset()`, is called; this method disposes of the WaveOut object and the Stream of the WaveOutReader. The event handler is also removed.

```
using NAudio.Vorbis;
using NAudio.Wave;

public partial class MainForm : Form {

    private VorbisWaveReader? vorbis = null;
    private WaveOut? oggPlayer = null;

    private void btnPlayAudio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPlayAudio.Enabled = false;
        btnStopPlayback.Enabled = true;
        vorbis = new VorbisWaveReader("OGG File path"));
        oggPlayer = WaveOutInit(vorbis);
        oggPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void btnStopPlayback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oggPlayer?.Stop();
        btnStopPlayback.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void WaveOut_PlaybackStopped(object? sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        WaveOutReset(oggPlayer, vorbis);
        btnPlayAudio.Enabled = true;
    }

    private WaveOut WaveOutInit(IWaveProvider reader)
    {
        var waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.PlaybackStopped += WaveOut_PlaybackStopped;
        waveOut.Init(reader);
        return waveOut;
    }

    private void WaveOutReset(WaveOut? player, VorbisWaveReader? reader)
    {
        if (player != null) {
            player.PlaybackStopped -= WaveOut_PlaybackStopped;
            player.Dispose();
        }
        reader?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: it return System.ArgumentException: 'Could not initialize container!'

Comment: Since it's just something you read, it can be stored it in the App's stating folder. In this case, you usually add a Folder to the Project, right-click it and select `Add -> Existing Item`, add an OGG file, select it and its Properties' panel, select `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer` Or you can add it as a Project Resource, as a File object. In this case it's stored as a byte array, so you need to create a Stream from it, as, e.g., `var oggStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.YourOGGobject)`